# Qt ui on top of c/c++ code

Tags: qt, qml, qt5

I saw this thread: [QML UI on top of OpenGL rendering in Qt5.3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25815047/qml-ui-on-top-of-opengl-rendering-in-qt5-3) but it's not what I am looking for.

My question is if I have a program already written in c/c++ and would like to add ui to it in the most cross platform way. Qt seems to be the way to go, is it possible to just link the Qt library 'hopefully not too large' into my application and create menus, buttons etc that work in a cross platform way?

I don't want to build my app using Qt, I just want to use the layout widgets, menus etc.

Comment: yes, it is quite common.

Comment: can you provide some links, looking at the qt site they seem to show qml app with opengl and not adding qml into an app that was not written by qml.

Comment: As I understand you have a program logics in C++ without GUI, is it right? I think the best way to connect it to Qt GUI is to make some shared library from that. After this you can create Qt Widget project, make all GUI you need and connect it to the library.

Comment: @folibis If that's the only way that I can do it I would prefer not to create a QT project. Would there be any other cross platform tools that you can use to create UI's that you can add to applications? It would be best if the UI can be linked into a c/c++ application.

Comment: I think there are tens of ways to do that. May be wxWindows ,Tk or GTK+. But in these choices you miss all the power of Qt. And I don't understand why you put Qt-related tags if you don't want it

Answer (score 0):

> I don't want to build my app using Qt, I just want to use the layout widgets, menus etc.

What?

In any case you should make an UI (using [Qt Widgets](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtwidgets-index.html) or [Qt Qml](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtqml-index.html)) and UI logic, and connect it to your app API. Just add UI layouts (using Qt Designer) and connect UI actions for button/menu/etc. to your app.
Qt - is the most cross-platform way to go, today.